# Kivy listview text alignment

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Is it possible to have dynamic text alignment with kivy listview?

I have a list of responses from a web lookup.
I would like to have the text alignment (left or center) of each list item depending on the quality of the response item.
I can't find a way to access 'halign' for each list item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own item class, I think this is an option on the ListAdapter (maybe named `cls`). In doing so, you can add whatever logic you like to how the item is displayed.